# Override default routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Can we override the default routing for resources provided by Rails? In my app I want new.html.erb to be accessed only by put method. But, by defining `map.resources :model` will give access with get method to new.html.erb and I want to change that. Can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate default route for your model, without the new action, you can use this instruction in your route file

```
resources :model, except: :new
```

And in the same file you'll add a non managed (i.e "manual") route for the new action

```
put "articles/new" => "articles#new"
```

Note: you can also use this syntax `match "articles/new" => "articles#new", via: :put` which allow you to easily add more methods in the future

More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to not declare the model as a resource in routes.rb, and setup the routes you want manually.

For instance if your model is Article, then you could just have in your routes.rb

```
put "articles/new" => "articles#new"
```

Which will match 'articles/new' to the new action, and restrict it to just the PUT method.